# Form on ASP.NET MVC Partial View only submits after hitting enter twice on textbox on MS Edge

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, microsoft-edge, ajax.beginform

**** Edit - Apparently this only happens on MS Edge. It works with a single Enter on Chrome and Firefox.**

I have a problem where a form is only submitted after I hit enter twice on a text box.

The form is extremely simple, just 1 text box and the submit button.

It all works fine if I explicitly hit the Submit button; data displays correctly and all, but I want to also submit by hitting enter. And I noticed that if i just hit enter once, it does not work. It isn't until I hit enter twice that the form actually submits.

I already tried binding to jquery's keypress, and even doing .live(), but even then it only works after hitting enter twice.

In case it's relevant, the reason I'm binding to DOMSubtreeModified on Search.cshtml is because I'm using the datatables.net jQuery plugin, and I could not find a way to call the .DataTable() method on the table after the form submits, so I had to call it after the HTML on the div changes.

My setup is as follows:

**Search.cshtml**

```
<div id="search-form">
@Html.Action("SearchForm", "Item")
</div>
<br />
<br />
<div id="search-results">
</div>

@section scripts {
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $('#search-results').bind("DOMSubtreeModified", function () {
            $('#items').DataTable();
        });
    </script>
}
```

**_SearchFormPartial.cshtml**

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Search", "Item", FormMethod.Post,
            new AjaxOptions
            {
                InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
                HttpMethod = "POST",
                UpdateTargetId = "search-results"
            }))
{
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <input type="text" id="term" name="term" placeholder="Search by Item Name" class="form-control" autofocus />
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2">
            <input type="submit" value="Search" id="btnSearch" class="btn btn-default" />
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

**_SearchResultsPartial.cshtml**

```
@model List<MyItem>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Search Results";
}

<table class="table table-striped" id="items">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td><strong>Name</strong></td>
            <td><strong>Type</strong></td>
            <td><strong>Status</strong></td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr class="clickable-row">
            <td>@item.Name</td>
            <td>@item.Type</td>
            <td>@item.Status</td>
        </tr>
    }

</table>

@section scripts {
    <script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#items tr").css('cursor', 'pointer');
        });

        $("#items tr.clickable-row").on('click', function (e, row, $element) {
            var url = $(this).closest('tr').children('td.secretLink').children(":first").attr("href");
            window.location = url;
        });
    </script>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked in Chrome and in IE edge when I clicked Enter once, for both browsers

https://dotnetfiddle.net/DUvLqb

Controller/ViewModel

```
namespace Testy20161006.Controllers
{
    public class MyItem
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Type { get; set; }
        public string Status { get; set; }
    }

    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult SearchForm()
        {
            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult SearchMe(string term)
        {
            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult Search()
        {
            var myItem1 = new MyItem { Name = "Name1", Status = "Stat1", Type = "Type1" };
            var myItem2 = new MyItem { Name = "Name2", Status = "Stat2", Type = "Type2" };
            var myItem3 = new MyItem { Name = "Name3", Status = "Stat3", Type = "Type3" };
            IList<MyItem> list = new List<MyItem>();
            list.Add(myItem1);
            list.Add(myItem2);
            list.Add(myItem3);

            return View(list);
        }
```

Search.cshtml

```
@model List<Testy20161006.Controllers.MyItem>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Search";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>Search</h2>

<div id="search-form">
    @*changing this action*@
    @*@Html.Action("SearchForm", "Item")*@
    @Html.ActionLink("Click to Search", "SearchForm")
</div>
<br />
<br />
<div id="search-results">
</div>

@Html.Partial("~/Views/Home/_SearchFormPartial.cshtml")
@Html.Partial("~/Views/Home/_SearchResultsPartial.cshtml", Model)

@section scripts {
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $('#search-results').bind("DOMSubtreeModified", function () {
            $('#items').DataTable();
        });
    </script>
}
```

_SearchFormPartial.cshtml

```
@*Changing Ajax.BeginForm Signature*@
@*@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Search", "Item", FormMethod.Post,
                new AjaxOptions
                {
                    InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
                    HttpMethod = "POST",
                    UpdateTargetId = "search-results"
                }))
    {*@
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("SearchMe", "Home", FormMethod.Post,
            new AjaxOptions
            {
                InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
                HttpMethod = "POST",
                UpdateTargetId = "search-results"
            }))
{
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <input type="text" id="term" name="term" placeholder="Search by Item Name" class="form-control" autofocus />
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2">
            <input type="submit" value="Search" id="btnSearch" class="btn btn-default" />
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

_SearchResultsPartial

```
@model List<Testy20161006.Controllers.MyItem>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Search Results";
}

<table class="table table-striped" id="items">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td><strong>Name</strong></td>
            <td><strong>Type</strong></td>
            <td><strong>Status</strong></td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr class="clickable-row">
            <td>@item.Name</td>
            <td>@item.Type</td>
            <td>@item.Status</td>
        </tr>
    }

</table>

@section scripts {
    <script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#items tr").css('cursor', 'pointer');
        });

        $("#items tr.clickable-row").on('click', function (e, row, $element) {
            var url = $(this).closest('tr').children('td.secretLink').children(":first").attr("href");
            window.location = url;
        });
    </script>
}
```